# Customizing Departments on the Intranet Portal site

Tags: kentico

A client is requesting that we change the default sections for a department website. I've created a department site with the appropriate sections and created a copy named "Template". My hope was when an administrator creates a new department site, it would generate all of the pages from the template. This is not the case and it looks like I need to modify the "Department Sections Manager" in the Department document but I'm not sure how to do this, or if this is the correct course of action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to create the `Template` as just a regular page and not a Department. After I created the `Template` page I added all of the sub pages and everything is working now.